# function and loop on column and unique ID

Tags: r, loops, apply

that's my data frame:

```
dput(fase1_M2)
structure(list(CO2 = c(1300L, 1300L, 1300L), Meso = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("M2", "M3", "M4", "M5", "M6", "M7", "M8"), class = "factor"), 
    Days = structure(c(18L, 8L, 2L), .Label = c("T1", "T-1", 
    "T11", "T13", "T15", "T17", "T19", "T-2", "T20", "T21", "T22", 
    "T23", "T24", "T25", "T27", "T29", "T3", "T-3", "T5", "T7", 
    "T9"), class = "factor"), Day = -3:-1, Total.abundance.cell.l = c(8298255, 
    78682211, 175454990), Tot.dinoflagellate.cell.l = c(879200L, 
    1101931L, 4293575L), Tot.diatoms.cell.l = c(7243215, 77580280, 
    171161415), Tot.other.cell.l = c(175840L, 0L, 0L), Amphidinium = c(NA, 
    NA, NA), Karenia.mikimotoi = c(NA, NA, NA), Heteocapsa = c(NA, 
    NA, NA), Gymnodiales = c(879199.999999999, 1101930.66666667, 
    4293574.68013468), Peridinella = c(NA, NA, NA), Prorocentrum = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), Gyrodinium = c(NA, NA, NA), Scripsiella = c(NA, 
    NA, NA), Protoperidinium.bipes = c(NA, NA, NA), Protoperidinium = c(NA, 
    NA, NA), Mesoporos.perforatus = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), Ceratium.fusus = c(NA, NA, NA), Katodinium = c(NA, NA, 
    NA), Gymnodinium = c(NA, NA, NA), Ceratium.lineatum = c(NA, 
    NA, NA), Nitzschia.longissima.min50 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), Nitzschia.longissima.mag50 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), Pseudo.nitzschia.min50 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), Pseudo.nitzschia.mag50 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), Licmophora = c(488250, NA, NA), Navicula = c(NA, 
    NA, NA), Skeletonema.costatum = c(270825, NA, 2797454.54545454
    ), Guinardia = c(NA, 54950000, NA), Guinardia...20. = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), Dactyliosolen = c(6264300, 22419600, 
    163184848.484849), Thalissiosia.constricta = c(NA, NA, NA
    ), Hemiliaulus.haukii = c(NA, NA, NA), Rhizosolenia = c(NA, 
    NA, NA), Helicotheca = c(NA, NA, NA), Chaetoceros.lorenzianus = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), Chaetoceros.affinis = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), Chaetoceros..10 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), Chaetoceros..10.1 = c(219840, 210680, 2493555.55555556
    ), Chaetoceros.decipiens = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), Chaetoceros.Didymus = c(NA, NA, NA), Leptocylindrus = c(NA, 
    NA, 2685556.36363636), Asterionellopsis.glacialis = c(NA, 
    NA, NA), Ceratulina = c(NA, NA, NA), Corethron = c(NA, NA, 
    NA), Thalassiosira.nitzschioide = c(NA, NA, NA), Dictyocha = c(NA, 
    NA, NA), Cylindrotheca = c(NA, NA, NA), thalassiosira = c(NA, 
    NA, NA), bacteriastrum.hyalinum = c(NA, NA, NA), Eutripsiella = c(NA, 
    NA, NA), Cryptonomas = c(175840, NA, NA), Olisthodiscus = c(NA, 
    NA, NA), trasparente.quadrato = c(NA, NA, NA), flagellate.rotonde = c(NA, 
    NA, NA), pleurosigma = c(NA, NA, NA), amphidinium.carterae = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), Actinoptychus.octonaria = c(NA, NA, 
    NA), pyramimonas = c(NA, NA, NA), acanthoica.aculata = c(NA, 
    NA, NA), Specie.fionda = c(NA, NA, NA), Asteroplans.Karianus = c(NA, 
    NA, NA), Chaetoceros.Lauderi = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), Chaetoceros.curvisetus = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
    ), Eucampia.Zodiacus = c(NA, NA, NA), Eunotia.clevei = c(NA, 
    NA, NA), Diplopsalis = c(NA, NA, NA), ceratium = c(NA, NA, 
    NA), Raphidophyce = c(NA, NA, NA), Chaetoceros.atlanticus = c(NA, 
    NA, NA), Guinardia.delicatula = c(NA, NA, NA), Leptocylindrus.5 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_)), .Names = c("CO2", "Meso", "Days", "Day", 
"Total.abundance.cell.l", "Tot.dinoflagellate.cell.l", "Tot.diatoms.cell.l", 
"Tot.other.cell.l", "Amphidinium", "Karenia.mikimotoi", "Heteocapsa", 
"Gymnodiales", "Peridinella", "Prorocentrum", "Gyrodinium", "Scripsiella", 
"Protoperidinium.bipes", "Protoperidinium", "Mesoporos.perforatus", 
"Ceratium.fusus", "Katodinium", "Gymnodinium", "Ceratium.lineatum", 
"Nitzschia.longissima.min50", "Nitzschia.longissima.mag50", "Pseudo.nitzschia.min50", 
"Pseudo.nitzschia.mag50", "Licmophora", "Navicula", "Skeletonema.costatum", 
"Guinardia", "Guinardia...20.", "Dactyliosolen", "Thalissiosia.constricta", 
"Hemiliaulus.haukii", "Rhizosolenia", "Helicotheca", "Chaetoceros.lorenzianus", 
"Chaetoceros.affinis", "Chaetoceros..10", "Chaetoceros..10.1", 
"Chaetoceros.decipiens", "Chaetoceros.Didymus", "Leptocylindrus", 
"Asterionellopsis.glacialis", "Ceratulina", "Corethron", "Thalassiosira.nitzschioide", 
"Dictyocha", "Cylindrotheca", "thalassiosira", "bacteriastrum.hyalinum", 
"Eutripsiella", "Cryptonomas", "Olisthodiscus", "trasparente.quadrato", 
"flagellate.rotonde", "pleurosigma", "amphidinium.carterae", 
"Actinoptychus.octonaria", "pyramimonas", "acanthoica.aculata", 
"Specie.fionda", "Asteroplans.Karianus", "Chaetoceros.Lauderi", 
"Chaetoceros.curvisetus", "Eucampia.Zodiacus", "Eunotia.clevei", 
"Diplopsalis", "ceratium", "Raphidophyce", "Chaetoceros.atlanticus", 
"Guinardia.delicatula", "Leptocylindrus.5"), row.names = c(1L, 
8L, 15L), class = "data.frame")
```

what I'm trying to do is do apply a function that for each column of the dataframe calculates the final `logaritmo`:

```
f=function(x) {
  MIN=apply(x,2,min,na.rm=T)
  MAX=apply(x,2,max,na.rm=T)
  MIN=as.numeric(MIN)
  MAX=as.numeric(MAX)
  logaritmo=log(MAX/MIN)
  t2=which.max( x)
  t1=which.min( x )
  logaritmo/(t2-t1)
}
```

then I would like to apply this function to all the columns of the dataframe so that I'll have the final result `logaritmo` for each column.

I tried to use:

```
apply(fase1_M2,2,f)
```

but it does not work..

Thanks for helping

Comment: What is the desired output? Do you want the function `f` to apply to the whole data frame or do you want to use it within an `apply` call?

Comment: You are passing columns in `f` by using `apply(fase1_M2,2,f)`. Then what is the meaning of `apply(x,2,min,na.rm=T)` inside your function `f`?

Comment: @thepule Actually I thought that I could be easier to write a function that work once at a time for each column and then apply this function to the whole dataframe. Output should be the numeric numer `logaritmo` calculated for each column (a `df` would be super ok)

Comment: So the output is the logarithm of the maximum / minimum for each column? I do not get what you want to divide the logarithm by at the end...what are `t1` and `t2` supposed to represent?

Comment: Also there are non numeric columns in your data frame and a lot of *NA*. How do you want to deal with them?

Comment: Not numeric column should not be a problem.. I mean, if there are some NA in the same column the calculation should be done, if the column is not numeric there is no problem if the result has not sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, this is what you are looking for (`df` is your data frame):

```
library(dplyr)

lapply(df, function(x) {
    if(class(x) == "numeric") log((max(x) / min(x) ) / (max(x) - min(x)) )
    else NA
    }
    ) %>% rbind() %>% data.frame() -> tt
```

Where the output `tt` is a data frame that contains the logarithm of max / min divided by the difference between the max and the min. For non *numeric* columns or columns containing *NA*, it will return *NA*.